# Find median of values based on multiple identifiers and add to row

Tags: python, pandas

I am a novice at this and am looking to solve the following problem. I have a data set with the search rank of SKUs based on multiple keyword searches that occur every day over the course of a week.

I would like to be able to add a column to my data in which I have the `median` (or `mean`, or `std`) of that SKU's search rank for that particular day.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv('searchdata.csv')

dfdataIwant = df[['Date', 'SKU', 'Search_Rank']]
print dfdataIwant.groupby(['Date','SKU']).median()
```

This gets me the `median` values I am looking for. However, what I want to do is take that `median` value and insert it in a new column. The `median` values I am inserting into this column should correspond with the correct date and SKU.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Remember to accept the answer if that helps you solve your question. People put their effort to help and you should at least pay respect to do so :)

Comment: Sorry! Will do a better job in the future. Thanks for the friendly reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `.transform()` if you want to assign the `.grouby()` aggregation result back to the original `DataFrame` ([see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation)):

```
df['median'] = data.groupby(['Date','SKU'])['Search Rank'].transform('median')
```

Available for the other stats you mention as well. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'rank': np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=500),
                        'SKU': np.random.choice(list('ABCDE'), replace=True, size=500),
                        'date': np.array([d for d in repeat(pd.date_range(start=date(2016,1,1), freq='D', periods=20), 25)]).flatten()})

df['median'] = df.groupby(['date','SKU'])['rank'].transform('median')
```

Results in:

```
df.sort_values(['date', 'SKU', 'rank'])

    SKU       date  rank  median
460   A 2016-01-01     4    66.0
80    A 2016-01-01    29    66.0
400   A 2016-01-01    38    66.0
220   A 2016-01-01    64    66.0
480   A 2016-01-01    68    66.0
160   A 2016-01-01    69    66.0
200   A 2016-01-01    70    66.0
360   A 2016-01-01    86    66.0
280   B 2016-01-01    14    22.0
300   B 2016-01-01    30    22.0
380   C 2016-01-01    35    63.0
240   C 2016-01-01    46    63.0
440   C 2016-01-01    63    63.0
20    C 2016-01-01    69    63.0
340   C 2016-01-01    91    63.0
100   D 2016-01-01    32    59.0
40    D 2016-01-01    38    59.0
120   D 2016-01-01    59    59.0
320   D 2016-01-01    77    59.0
260   D 2016-01-01    94    59.0
0     E 2016-01-01    31    60.0
420   E 2016-01-01    35    60.0
140   E 2016-01-01    60    60.0
60    E 2016-01-01    64    60.0
180   E 2016-01-01    99    60.0
441   A 2016-01-02    35    52.0
281   A 2016-01-02    52    52.0
481   A 2016-01-02    71    52.0
341   B 2016-01-02    73    88.0
81    B 2016-01-02    81    88.0
..   ..        ...   ...     ...
418   D 2016-01-19    98    71.5
38    E 2016-01-19    50    54.0
458   E 2016-01-19    51    54.0
478   E 2016-01-19    57    54.0
18    E 2016-01-19    71    54.0
439   A 2016-01-20     9    45.0
499   A 2016-01-20    45    45.0
99    A 2016-01-20    63    45.0
279   B 2016-01-20    12    55.5
339   B 2016-01-20    29    55.5
459   B 2016-01-20    44    55.5
379   B 2016-01-20    53    55.5
319   B 2016-01-20    58    55.5
39    B 2016-01-20    84    55.5
299   B 2016-01-20    94    55.5
119   B 2016-01-20    98    55.5
199   C 2016-01-20    15    43.0
159   C 2016-01-20    43    43.0
479   C 2016-01-20    90    43.0
259   D 2016-01-20    12    33.0
419   D 2016-01-20    13    33.0
59    D 2016-01-20    15    33.0
139   D 2016-01-20    31    33.0
79    D 2016-01-20    33    33.0
19    D 2016-01-20    42    33.0
239   D 2016-01-20    46    33.0
399   D 2016-01-20    54    33.0
219   D 2016-01-20    63    33.0
179   E 2016-01-20    27    53.5
359   E 2016-01-20    80    53.5
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, 

This worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your help.